# Hello, i have a porcelain with these symbols on it. can someone help me decifer them ? Huge thanks

Tags: translation

the titles say's it, i have some old porcelain form china at home, and i would really like to know the meaning of the symbols in the photo attached. thank you!

[image]

Comment: Image grabbed from https://www.gotheborg.com/marks/20thcenturyjapan.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Your porcelain is from Japan as it says Great Japan (大日本) .... This mark was intended to be read from the right then up to the top & left.

[item/photo#]: “1090. Mark: "Dai Nichi Hon" (Great Japan) over a sign meaning "roof/house" and the number "three", early 20th century. It is generally accepted that marks that includes "Dai Nippon" in Japanese characters on the whole date to the Meiji (1868-1912) period, reflecting the greatly increased nationalism of that period.

I found that pottery info at the webpage below & you can send a photo that pottery expert for more info.... https://www.gotheborg.com/marks/20thcenturyjapan.shtml

Answer (score 0):

日: (Sun， Pinyin:rì)

本: (Origin， Pinyin：běn)

大: (Big， Pinyin : dà)

三: (Three, pinyin :sān)

日本 ：(Japan, Pinyin : rì běn）

Comment: Thanks, any idea if it's a concept of some sort, how it is red ?